# Victoria metric increase() function outputs very high values

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I am new to victoria metrics and trying to send some data to VM using exposition format. Basically I have a csv data , I am reading csv and creating a exposition string separated by \n, in format metric_name{label=label_value} counter current epoch mili.
The counter is monotonically increasing.
label has 100 different values.

I am able to send the data to VM with 1 sample every 10 sec.

When I apply increase function for duration of 2m increase(metric[2m]) this gives me many time series due to cardinality of label, but if I do sum(increase(metric[2m])) I was assuming this would give me correct output but this provides very high numbers which do not align with the data I am sending.

My calculations :
6 counter increase in 1 min.

min counter

---

0.   0

---

1. 6

   ---
2. 12

   ---
3. 18

   ---

Assumption the increase should provide constant number.

Do let me know if I missed something or doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data in Prometheus text exposition format you are trying to ingest into VictoriaMetrics?

Comment: 'transactions_data{completed="1", failed="0", name='+'"'+str(name1)+'"'+'} '+str(1)+" "+str(time.time()*1000)\n
'transactions_data{completed="1", failed="0", name='+'"'+str(name2)+'"'+'} '+str(2)+" "+str(time.time()*1000)\n
'transactions_data{completed="1", failed="0", name='+'"'+str(name1)+'"'+'} '+str(3)+" "+str(time.time()*1000)\n
..and so on.

Then I am using sum(increase(transactions_data[10m])) to get all transactions within 10m.



I am sure something I am doing is  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a confusion between [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) and [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) metric types. Counter metric should increase over time, while gauge metric can have arbitrary values over time. If you push gauge metrics into VictoriaMetrics, then you need to use [sum_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) function instead of [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase).

See also [Prometheus key concepts](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html).